# django template styntex {% if p.category == "help" %} {% endif %} is not work

Tags: django, if-statement, templates

As a result of executing the code below

```
{{p.category}} <!-- help -->
{% if p.category == "help" %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" style="color:blue;">
        <a href="{% url "todo:todo_help" p.pk %}" >help 11</a>
    </button>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">
        <a href="{% url "todo:todo_help" p.pk %}" >help 22 </a>
    </button>
{% endif %}
```

I expected the help11 button to be output.

The reason is that {{p.category} is 'help'

But the output button was help22.

I do not know why that's not work

Is this comparison logic wrong?

If you know the reason, please let me know.

view

```
class TodoList(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Todo
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            return Todo.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        else:
            return Todo.objects.filter(Q(author=self.request.user) & Q(elapsed_time__isnull=True)).order_by('-created')

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(TodoList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['todos_without_category'] = Todo.objects.filter(category=None).count()

        context['todo_count_uncomplete'] = Todo.objects.filter(Q(author=self.request.user) & Q(elapsed_time__isnull=True)).count()
        context['todo_count_complete'] = Todo.objects.filter(Q(author=self.request.user) & Q(elapsed_time__isnull=False)).count()

        context['total_todo_count_uncomplete'] = Todo.objects.filter(Q(elapsed_time__isnull=True)).count()
        context['total_todo_count_complete'] = Todo.objects.filter(Q(elapsed_time__isnull=False)).count()

        return context
```

screen shot
[image]

models.py (category field)

```
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

category model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, allow_unicode=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/todo/category/{}/'.format(self.slug)
```

Comment: Just for debugging: What if you write `if str(p.category) == "help"`, what happens?

Comment: Your category is likely a `Category` object with a `name`? Can you share your `Category` model? probably the check is `{% if p.category.name == ... %}`.

Comment: Guess your `p.category` is not string. Provide `views.py`

Comment: @ArupRakshit: you can not make function calls with arguments in a Django template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh I see. :) I was thinking it as a Python.

Comment: post your view.py code

Comment: There is no error, and the output of {{p.category}} is 'help'

Comment: @HyK: the view is not that interesting, the interesting part is the `Category` model.

Comment: @HyK you should use `{% if p.category.name== "help" %}` indeed

Answer (score 4):

If you check:

```
{% if p.category == "help" %}
```

then you check if the `.category` of `p` is a string `"help"`. But `.category` is a `Category` object, *not* a string. A `Category` with the name `"help"` is not the same as `"help"`. Its *textual representation* (implemented with `__str__`) is however `"help"`, that is why `{{ p.category }}` will indeed yield `"help"`.

You thus need to check with the `.name` of the category here, like:

```
{% if p.category.name == "help" %}
```